# Vuetify: Specifying the height of list items in v-autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using a `v-autocomplete` with a [custom slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#advanced-slots) to display results:

```
<v-autocomplete :items=searchResults :loading=loading :search-input.sync="query" hide-no-data label="Entreprise, SIREN..." append-icon="search" v-model="selected" three-line >
  <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
    <v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-tile-title>
      <v-list-tile-sub-title v-text="item.value"></v-list-tile-sub-title>
      >
      <v-list-tile-sub-title> Third line of list item</v-list-tile-sub-title>
    </v-list-tile-content>
    <CompanyListItem :company=item :loading=false />
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Unfortunately the resulting list items appear compressed vertically, as seen in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/coyotte508/pen/oOJLLd).

Is it possible to add `two-line` or `three-line` to the underlying list to be able to have 'taller' list items? Adding those properties to the `<v-autocomplete>` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the height of list tile to **auto** as CSS property worked for me .

```
.v-autocomplete__content .v-list__tile{
  height: auto;
}
```

**two-line** or **three-line** are props of `<v-list></v-list>` to increase list-tile height.But here the contents of **v-slot:item** are by default wrapped in `<v-list></v-list>` (when i inspect the element in browser inspector).

Comment: This works in the main.css file, which updates all of the files and creates confusion. Rather, I would like to customize the components locally in the style section of the component. How is that possible?